# How to get a single result with columns from multiple records in a single table?

Tags: sql, oracle

**Platform:** Oracle 10g

I have a table (let's call it `t1`) like this:

```
ID  | FK_ID | SOME_VALUE | SOME_DATE
----+-------+------------+-----------
1   | 101   | 10         | 1-JAN-2013
2   | 101   | 20         | 1-JAN-2014
3   | 101   | 30         | 1-JAN-2015
4   | 102   | 150        | 1-JAN-2013
5   | 102   | 250        | 1-JAN-2014
6   | 102   | 350        | 1-JAN-2015
```

For each `FK_ID` I wish to show a single result showing the two most recent `SOME_VALUE`s. That is:

```
FK_ID | CURRENT | PREVIOUS
------+---------+---------
101   | 30      | 20
102   | 350     | 250
```

There is another table (lets call it `t2`) for the `FK_ID`, and it is here that there is a reference
saying which is the 'CURRENT' record. So a table like:

```
ID  | FK_CURRENT | OTHER_FIELDS
----+------------+-------------
101 | 3          | ...
102 | 6          | ...
```

I was attempting this with a  **flawed** sub query join along the lines of:

```
SELECT id, curr.some_value as current, prev.some_value as previous FROM t2
  JOIN t1 curr ON t2.fk_current = t1.id 
  JOIN t1 prev ON t1.id = (
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SOME_DATE DESC) as rno FROM t1
          WHERE t1.fk_id = t2.id
      ) WHERE rno = 2
    )
  )
```

However the `t1.fk_id = t2.id` is flawed (i.e. wont run), as (I now know) you can't pass a parent
field value into a sub query more than one level deep.

Then I started wondering if Common Table Expressions (CTE) are the tool for this, but then I've no
experience using these (so would like to know I'm not going down the wrong track attempting to use them - if that is the tool).

So I guess the key complexity that is tripping me up is:

- Determining the previous value by ordering, but while limiting it to the first record (and not the whole table). (Hence the somewhat convoluted sub query attempt.)

Otherwise, I can just write some code to first execute a query to get the 'current' value, and then
execute a second query to get the 'previous' - but I'd love to know how to solve this with a single
SQL query as it seems this would be a common enough thing to do (sure is with the DB I need to work
with).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an approach with LAG function:

```
SELECT FK_ID , 
       SOME_VALUE as "CURRENT", 
       PREV_VALUE as Previous
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,
           lag( some_value ) over (partition by fk_id order by some_date ) prev_value
    FROM t1
) x
JOIN t2 on t2.id = x.fk_id
     and t2.fk_current = x.id
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d3e640/15

Comment: Great answer (especially with supporting sqlfiddle). Works a treat and shows I need to read up and start understanding the analytic methods. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try out this:

```
select t1.FK_ID ,t1.SOME_VALUE as CURRENT,
(select SOME_VALUE from t1 where p1.id2=t1.id and t1.fk_id=p1.fk_id) as PREVIOUS 
from  t1 inner join
(
  select t1.fk_id, max(t1.id) as id1,max(t1.id)-1 as id2 from  t1 group by t1.FK_ID 
) as p1 on t1.id=p1.id1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Interesting idea in ignoring the date, however that is a key business rule; and your answer ignored the FK_CURRENT - but that is rather important (as the newest item with an ID may simply be a draft record - and thereby not current).